# Mapbox - Uploaded GeoTIFF file has no bounds

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, mapbox

I'm trying to add GCP data to an old map and then upload it as a tileset to Mapbox. I've managed to add the data using Georeferencer and the output in qgis looks okay, but when I upload it as a tileset to Mapbox it doesn't show me any preview and when I try to add it as a layer I get an error saying "This tileset isn't visible from your map view".

For reference, "no preview" means:

[image]

It gives me these details after the upload:

[image]

That seems a little odd to me so I attempted to use the command line tools to find out what's in the TIFF.

If I use `gdalinfo` on the file (with an argument of `-proj4`), it outputs what looks like reasonable output for Corner Coordinates:

```
Upper Left  (  -6.3427176,  53.3848600) (  0d 0' 0.21"W,  0d 0' 1.73"N)
Lower Left  (  -6.3427176,  53.3155539) (  0d 0' 0.21"W,  0d 0' 1.72"N)
Upper Right (  -6.1930269,  53.3848600) (  0d 0' 0.20"W,  0d 0' 1.73"N)
Lower Right (  -6.1930269,  53.3155539) (  0d 0' 0.20"W,  0d 0' 1.72"N)
Center      (  -6.2678722,  53.3502069) (  0d 0' 0.20"W,  0d 0' 1.73"N)
```

But the proj.4 string is `'+proj=merc +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6378137 +units=m +no_defs'`.

Are those 0s for lat and long messing things up for me, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

I'm a QGIS noob so step by step instructions might be needed.